# need to modify the query without using cross/outer apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
create table PrinterData(
    Dt DateTime not null,
    Status nvarchar(50) not null    
)

insert into PrinterData
values
('05.24.2019 00:00:00', 'READY'),
('05.24.2019 00:01:00', 'READY'),
('05.24.2019 00:02:00', 'NO PAPER'),
('05.24.2019 00:03:00', 'UNKNOWN'),
('05.24.2019 00:04:00', 'UNKNOWN'),
('05.24.2019 00:05:00', 'READY'),
('05.24.2019 00:06:00', 'READY'),
('05.24.2019 00:07:00', 'READY'),
('05.24.2019 00:08:00', 'NO PAPER'),
('05.24.2019 00:09:00', 'UNKNOWN'),
('05.24.2019 00:10:00', 'HAS PAPER'),
('05.24.2019 00:11:00', 'NO PAPER')
```

I need to know the time interval between *READY* status and next *READY* or *HAS PAPER*, except *UNKNOWN* status. *UNKNOWN* i need to skip.
The result should look like this:

[image]

This is my query , but i don't like to use cross/outer apply. In terms of performance and speed i need your suggestion, how to modify this query.

```
select a.Dt, a.Status, b.Dt as Dt_Next_Status, b.Status as Next_Status, DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.Dt, b.Dt) as Diff from PrinterData a
outer apply 
(
    select top 1  Dt, Status from PrinterData where Dt > a.Dt and Status not in ('UNKNOWN', 'NO PAPER') 
) b
where a.Status = 'NO PAPER'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lead()` function

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c5dfbd2ea0f58b7f15074536596bcf9c)**

```
select *,datediff(SECOND,dt,nexttime) as diff from 
(
select *,lead(dt) over(order by dt) as nexttime,lead(status) over(order by dt) as nextstatus
from PrinterData
where Status<>'UNKNOWN'
)A where status='NO PAPER'
```

OUTPUT:

```
Dt                  Status      nexttime            nextstatus  diff
24/05/2019 00:02:00 NO PAPER    24/05/2019 00:05:00 READY       180
24/05/2019 00:08:00 NO PAPER    24/05/2019 00:10:00 HAS PAPER   120
24/05/2019 00:11:00 NO PAPER
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by using left join and row_number()

```
with cte as
(
select a.Dt, a.Status, b.Dt as Dt_Next_Status, b.Status as Next_Status,
DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.Dt, b.Dt) as Diff,
row_number()over(partition by a.DT order by b.Dt) rn
from PrinterData a
left join
(
    select  Dt, Status from PrinterData where Status not in ('UNKNOWN', 'NO PAPER') 
) b on  b.Dt > a.Dt
where a.Status = 'NO PAPER' 
) 
select * from cte where rn=1
```

[demo in fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8529e4ef2657d6e2745de13e368501a4)